# Visual studio code is not recognising $ in javascript editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am writing the following code in my VS code editor.

```
let name="Sam";
const   val =  "I am  $ {name}";

console.log(val);
```

when I display it in console it should display" I am Sam" .But it is printing "I am  $ {name}"

I have added extention of "JS ES6" and "Live Server"
I am  a beginner and unable to understand what  I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use backticks `\``, not quotes `"`. Also it's `${name}` not `$ {name}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define it as a template string, replace the " with ` and for the variable you have to remove the space between $ and {

```js
let name="Sam";
const myval = `I am ${name}`;

console.log(myval);
```

For advanced description see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I took the liberty to make a snippet so we can see your code in action.